# Excel Macro - Merging workbooks, finding last row in a particular column

Tags: vba

hope someone can help me out. I'm trying to merge data from a sheet in multiple workbooks into one. I managed to get something to work, but I need to modify the below code. I need to search for the last row to copy, based on a set column, and not all columns. How can I modify the below code? Appreciate any help, thank you!!

```
    Private Function LastRow() As Long
        LastRow = 0
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) > 0 Then
            'Search for any entry, by searching backwards by Rows.
            LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[a1], _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        End If
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the last row of a column that has data in it

```
Dim LastRowOnColumn2 as Long
LastRowOnColumn2 = Activesheet.Cells(Activesheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
```